# Search and replace with Notepad++ keeping after defined string

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I have a file with content:

```
http://domain1.tld/random1/random11/random111/file1.jpg
http://domain2.tld/random12/file2.jpg
http://domain3.tld/file3.jpg
http://sub1.domain4.tld/blah/blahblah/file4.jpg
```

I want to search and replace to:

```
file1.jpg
file2.jpg
file3.jpg
file4.jpg
```

Comment: hi Phuong, why have you marked this question with elasticsearch ?

Answer (score 2):

Use the following regex in find:

`.+\/(.*)$`

All it is doing is matching everything until a `'\'` is encountered (greedily) and then capturing everything till the end of the line.

Replace it with:

`$1`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/88833Z/1)

Make sure you select the Regular Expression option in Notepad++. Note that this will also work for all file extensions, and not just `.jpg`.

Answer (score 1):

On notepad++ you should find search and replace by regex pattern, then you can use this following regex as search criteria :

`.+\/(\w+\.jpg)$` Be sure regex have multiline flag. this regex will capture each lines who looks like url/path whitch target jpg file and create temporally `$1` where will be stored file name.

then you replace by :

`$1\n`

Comment: Super, i am glad to help you. Please consider mark this answer as solve to inform other member of the community this question is solved.

Answer (score 0):

This removes everything upto the last slash in a line:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.+/`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *UNCHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^       # beginning of line
  .+    # 1 or more any character but newline
  /     # slash
```

**Result for given example:**

```
file1.jpg
file2.jpg
file3.jpg
file4.jpg
```